# Set segmented control font for any width class size

Tags: ios, swift

I like to increase font size for iPads only so I used the following

```
 let attr = NSDictionary(object: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 16.0)!, forKey: NSFontAttributeName as NSCopying)
```

and in `viewDidLoad()`

```
segmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes(attr as [NSObject : AnyObject] , for: .normal)
```

but this increases fonts in both iPhone and iPad.I like to know how to increase font only in iPads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check device model:

```
let model = UIDevice.currentDevice().model

if model == "iPad" {
    let attr = NSDictionary(object: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 16.0)!, forKey: NSFontAttributeName as NSCopying)
    segmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes(attr as [NSObject : AnyObject] , for: .normal)
}else{
    let attr = NSDictionary(object: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 16.0)!, forKey: NSFontAttributeName as NSCopying)
    segmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes(attr as [NSObject : AnyObject] , for: .normal)
}
```

The code can be better.